# How to divert to report with expression in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, reportingservices-2005

Hi I have a SSRS Report in which i get a table report.

```
 ╔══════════════╦════════════════╦════════════════╗
 ║ Company Name ║ Customer Count ║ Employee Count ║
 ╠══════════════╬════════════════╬════════════════╣
 ║ Company A    ║ 1000           ║ 50             ║
 ╠══════════════╬════════════════╬════════════════╣
 ║ Company B    ║ 2000           ║ 100            ║
 ╠══════════════╬════════════════╬════════════════╣
 ║ Company C    ║ 3000           ║ 150            ║
 ╚══════════════╩════════════════╩════════════════╝
```

I want to go to report by Company Name.

Suppose if User click on `Company A` Then it should go to Report `CompanyAReport`.

If i click on `Company B` it should redirect to `CompanyBReport`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Achieve this scenario you have to create a separate report which will load details of the company.
So another report which might be drill down report of the company which gives list all Employees or customers of the company.

And you have to put the link on your report to redirect to another report with the parameters like.

In your report there will be tablix in which you will display all companies data. In that tablix textbox for CompanyName you have to open the property window like in below image.

[image]

in above image for textbox property there will be Action tab in that you can set action (href) where you want to redirect when user clicks on company name. You can also set the parameters of the report that you need to pass to open that report.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the company report will be the same  for both Company A and Company B then..

Create a new report ()called say, `_subCompanyReport`) that takes a parameter `CompanyName`.

Build a dataset that gets the info you need e.g. `SELECT * FROM myCompanyTable WHERE CompanyName = @CompanyName`

Add whatever you need to show on that report.

Go back to your original report, right-click the company name cell and and choose `textbox properties`.

Click `Action`, select `Go to Report`, choose `_subCompanyReport` from the report list

Click `Add` to add a parameters, choose or type `CompanyName` (case sensitive) in the Name field and finally select the "Company name" column from your report in the Value field.

That's pretty much it. If you have problems, makes sure all parameter names are spelled correctly, they are case sensitive.